# How to structure component when using new Audio in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to React so getting to grip with thinking in React.

I want to play an audio clip when a user clicks on a button in React. I want the know the best way to set up the `component` so that I have the audio in the correct method of the component.

In my 'app' have 3 songs, but I only want to create one instance of the Audio object.

In jQuery I would do something like this:

```
var songs = ['1.mp3', '2.mp3', '3.mp3'];
var i = 0;
var audio = new Audio();

$('.play').click(function(){
   audio.src = songs[i];
   audio.play();
});

$('.next').click(function(){
   i++;
   audio.src = songs[i];
   audio.play();
});
```

Currently my react code looks like below. Perhaps I am using `componentDidMount` incorrectly? Do I need to set `state` somewhere? or does it need to be a `prop`?

```
var Player = React.createClass({

   componentDidMount: function() {
      var audio = new Audio();
      audio.src = "test.mp3"
   },

   playSong: function() {  
     console.log(audio)
     audio.play();
   },

   render: function(){
     return(
       <div className="footer">
         <i onClick={this.playSong} className="play"></i>
         <i className="pause"></i>
         <i className="next-song"></i>
       </div>
     )
   }
 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have a prop of `audioSources` and have that be an array of mp3 file names. You could then also have a state of `activeAudioIndex` on your Player component and when it first loads do something like:

```
// set audio as a property of component `this.audio` can be accessed anywhere in component
audio: new Audio(), 

getInitialState: function() { 
  return {
   activeAudioIndex: 0
  }
},

componentDidMount: function() {
  this.audio.src = this.props.audioSources[this.state.activeAudioIndex]
}

nextSong: function() {
  var nextSongIndex = this.state.activeAudioIndex + 1 
  this.audio.src = this.props.audioSources[nextSongIndex]
  this.setState({activeAudioIndex: nextSongIndex})
}

playSong: function() {
  this.audio.play()
}
```

and then when you are actually using this component can do

```
<Player audioSources={['1.mp3', '2.mp3', '3.mp3']} />
```

Comment: i think it needs to be `<Player audioSources={['1.mp3', '2.mp3', '3.mp3']} />`

Comment: Thank you @phantom got the typo fixed

Comment: if the audioSources are coming from an AJAX request how should i add this props? is there something similar to `setState` for `props`?

Comment: If it were me, I'd have a `<PlayerContainer />` that wraps the `<Player />` component and manages all state and data. the PlayerContainer would be a high-order component and Player would just be for rendering. The Playercontainer would be what manages the audioSources as state and in its componentDidMount you can do the api calls and then when they finish you can set the state of the audio sources to the result of the api call. You'd need to handle the async parts however you want, aka what does it look like when we are waiting for data.

Comment: this is a great article on presentational vs functional/container components https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0#.cnd5uoxiy

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124469/discussion-between-phantom-and-finalfreq).